# How to auto resize label font size in iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, font-size, uifont

The fonts I see on iPhone 6 Plus seems too small. Fonts throughout the app differ in sizes. So the font size is not same in all screen. And I know that by putting condition to identify device and setting font size is not a good practice. I am not using autolayout. Everything I create is using programming. So what is the best way to auto size fonts?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is `UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(_:)`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/preferredFontForTextStyle:) is the documentation for that method. It will return you a system font based on the user's text size preference.